# Airflow Connection: How to create an airflow connection to Azure Blob Storage using Service Principal?

Tags: azure, airflow, azure-blob-storage

I followed this [doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure/stable/connections/wasb.html) to attempt to create an Azure Blob Storage connection.  I believe for my case, I am looking to connect via *token credentials*.

However I get an error when trying to save with no error message.  I'm a bit confused on whether I am providing **client_id, tenant_id, client_secret, sub_id**, etc. in the appropriate location as the UI doesn't specify those exact words except for tenant id. In the blob storage key (optional) input I have provided the client secret, and blob storage login (optional) holds the account name.  For the extra section, do the values need to follow "extra__azure__..."?

Any suggestion are highly appreciated!

[image]

I am able to connect to the Blob Storage via azure cli. Airflow version is 2.4.3 running on Kubernetes as a Docker container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To connect airflow with service principal to azure blob storage.**

- **First you need to create Service principal for appropriate azure application and get following details:**

--   Application Client ID

--   Tenant ID

--  Client secret

- **Assign Storage Blob Data Contributor role to your service principal in azure blob storage so that Airflow can access blob objects.**
- **Fill below feilds and test the connection**

--   Connection Id : Enter a name for the connection.

--  Account Name : Enter  **Blob Service URL**  for your storage account. eg. `https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/`

--  Blob Storage Login : Enter your  **Application (client) ID**.

--  Blob Storage Key : Enter your client secret  **Value**.

--  Tenant Id : Enter your  **Directory (tenant) ID**.

REFERENCE : [Create an Azure Blob Storage connection in Airflow](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/connections/azure-blob-storage#:%7E:text=available%20in%20Airflow.-,In%20the%20Airflow%20UI%20for%20your%20local%20Airflow%20environment%2C%20go,a%20name%20for%20the%20connection.)